# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error with AngularJS and Flask-Socketio

Tags: angularjs, flask, socket.io, cors

I am trying to make Flask-Socketio connection from AngularJS at client side to a Flask server.

Connecting with the Flask server works fine, but when I try to connect to socketio in my Angular controller:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
```

I see the following error on my browser console:

> Failed to load
>   http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1526477253000-2:
>   The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
>   must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

My client side (AngularJS) is running on port 3000 (gulp) and Flask server is running on port 5000.

I have tried including `flask_cors` with:

```
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

But still get the same issue.

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

instead of star mention you are host with port

Comment: Thanks Harsha, but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Actually it seemed to work when I disabled the CORS. I had a Chrome extension to enable CORS and when I disabled it, this seems to work. Thanks.!